# Fiddler2: Decrypt HTTPS traffic and Tunnel to host:443

Tags: fiddler

I use Fiddler2 to analyse some pages that use https connections. I enabled HTTPS decryption, but I still see some Tunnel to host:443 entries in my log. I can see decrypted HTTPS traffic in the log, so I assume the decyption works.

I think, that a Tunnel to host:443 entry is created in addition to the decrypted log entry when the connection is opened.

Is my assumption correct or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected.

If you click on `Tunnel to Host:443` you'll see the following on the *Statistics* tab:

```
The selected session is a HTTP CONNECT Tunnel. This tunnel enables a client to 
send raw traffic (e.g. HTTPS-encrypted streams or WebSocket messages) through 
a HTTP Proxy Server (like Fiddler).
```

You can automatically hide these tunnels if you like by clicking `Rules` > `Hide Connects`.

Answer (score 0):

My HTTPS interception and decryption stopped working and this message was also in my logs.

Perhaps it is unrelated but I was able to resolve but exporting the Fiddler certificate to Desktop (Tools > Fiddler Options > Export Root Certificate to Desktop), double clicking it to install it and restarting Fiddler and my Browser.

[image: fiddler-re-export-certificate-tunnel-to-host-issue]